# GetHostAddresses different error codes

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, network-programming

I wrote a small test program that used `Dns.GetHostAddresses` to resolve a host name. If I entered a hostname that didn't exist, it would throw a `SocketException` and the message would be `No such host is known`.
I liked this because the error message was small enough to put into my UI, and straight to the point.

Now I literally copied and pasted the code into a somewhat larger project, but this time when I enter the exact same hostname I did in my test project, it throws a `SocketException` but the message is set to `The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found`

Both the stack traces are the same in each program, but the first ones error is `WSAHOST_NOT_FOUND` where the second one is `WSANO_DATA`.

I could just output my own error message, but I would like to know why it's throwing a different error each time? There are no differences in the code.

Also, it seems that no matter how many times I run each program, they each keep outputting the same error message. It's not alternating or anything.

**===========================================================================**

Well I figured out what was causing the problem.
I added Pcap.Net as a reference and was including it in my project with `using PcapDotNet.Core;`
Anyways, after I commented that out, `Dns.GetHostAddresses` was throwing the correct exception.

If anyone could tell me why its behaving like that, and how to get around it, that would be great.

Comment: Are both the small test project and the other project building to the same version of .NET?

Comment: Are both projects running on the same machine\network domain?  The first error means that the host can't be found at all; the second error indicates that the host exists, but has incomplete data (i.e. no A record defined).

Comment: @ColeCampbell Yup, I ran both projects just now on my laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's many reasons why a `SocketException` will occur in `GetHostAddresses`.  In the case of `WSA_NODATA`, that means there is an entry in DNS; but no IP address (i.e. no A record).  You may get a different error if you can't reach the DNS server but the data is cached.  Or, you may get a different error if the DNS server is unreachable and the data isn't cached.  Etc.  Unfortunately `GetHostAddresses` wrap all those errors in one exception type.  If you want to do something different for each type of error, you'll have to check a relevant property in `SocketException`.  If you just want to detect that "it didn't work", then you don't have to check.  But, it's clear that `SocketException` message is different depending on the failure so I wouldn't recommend just using `Message`.  Not to mention, that will get translated on other language versions of Windows--so, it might look strange if the rest of your application is English, except for this message.

Technically it could have one of the following errors: `WSANOTINITIALIZED`, `WSAENETDOWN`, `WSAHOST_NOT_FOUND`, `WSATRY_AGAIN`, `WSANO_RECOVERY`, `WSANO_DATA`, `WSAEINPROGRESS`, `WSAEFAULT` and `WSAEINTR`.  Although some are extremely unlikely.

I also think you'll get different messages depending on whether IPv6 or IPv4 is in play.